# $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$ has a solution $\iff a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime and $a$ such that $gcd(p,a)=1$. Show that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$ has a solution $\iff a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

I think I should use [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) or [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), but I really don't know how to start the proof. Could please help me with a simple proof?

Comment: `\pmod{p}` is the command that produces the space, parentheses, and roman typeface "mod".

Comment: Cf. [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, I have changed it.

Comment: @MH.Lee Yes, thank you very much. Although I don't understand the "$\Longleftarrow$" direction. How do we know that $a\equiv g^t \pmod{p}$?

Comment: @AlejandroPeralta We know there exists a $t$ where $a \equiv g^{t}\pmod{p}$ by the definition of [Primitive root modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n), i.e., "... a number $g$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if every number $a$ coprime to $n$ is congruent to a power of $g$ modulo $n$". Also, every prime has a primitive root, as that article later states that Gauss "... was the first to rigorously demonstrate that primitive roots exist for a prime $n$".